# Creating a table where the primary key will be from two different table oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle11g

I have 3 tables. The schema is given bellow :

Employee        (**NID**, Name, Salary, Designation, Phone, Branch)

Client          (**NID**, Name, Insurance_type, Phone, Address, is_active, Pay_per_month, Start_year, End_year)

Payment      (**NID**, Payable, Receivable)

The payment tables primary key will be NID which will be inherited from Employee and Client table. If we merge both NID columns from the Employee and Client Tables the all NID will be unique. Is there any way to make such table where NID will be inherited from both client and Employee table in oracle 11g?

Comment: If `nid` is the primary key of `payment`, that would mean that each `employee` and `client` could have at most 1 payment.  That seems really unlikely.  Perhaps you mean that you want the `nid` to be a foreign key and to have a separate `payment_id` that is the primary key?

Comment: The employee and client will have at most 1 payment. The purpose of this table is to check if there is any due or receivable payments for any specific person with nid x. Every nid in the whole database is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like a workable design.

The standard way to do this is to have a separate foreign key in the `PAYMENT` table for each parent, i.e.:

`Payment (NID, NID_Client, NID_Emp, Payable, Receivable)`

Where NID - unique key for the PAYMENT table

NID_Client is the Client.NID value

NID_Emp is the Employee.NID value

To add the FK constraints:

```
alter table payment ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_Emp
    FOREIGN KEY (NID_Emp) REFERENCES Employee(NID);

alter table payment ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_Client
    FOREIGN KEY (NID_Client) REFERENCES Client(NID);
```

Comment: Every NID in the whole database is unique. Still we can't merge them?

Comment: No. Well, you could have Payment NID = Emp NID || Client NID, and then rely on complex coding to extract each component value, but it's an over-engineered and flaky solution to a problem that really is all in the mind. It cannot be enforced by the out of the box FK mechanisms, so you'd have top build your own.  I see no upsides to it, other than it being an interesting technical exercise.